# how to make an external hard drive unbootable

Tags: boot, external-hard-drive

Whenever I connect my external hard disk to the PC while booting up, It is requesting to remove the external hard disk as it doesn't have an OS.Is there any way to make the external hard disk "unbootable" so I don't need to remove the external hard disk every time the computer boots up.

Comment: You should set the intended boot device order at BIOS/UEFI.

Comment: Make your internal system hard disk as the primary boot order. Turn off USB legacy support.

Answer (score 1):

Change the order of the booting devices in your BIOS. 
Change your HDD or SSD to the first priority.